# How many (android) phones really still use hdpi or mdpi?

Tags: android

we are working on an app and always resize our drawables 5x for xxx xx x h and mdpi. We are just wondering how many phones actually use the two resolutions: mdpi and hdpi? The question is, if its still neccissary to support those. This is a question of overall size of the app. The more we can save the better. 
And if you guys know that for example less than 5 percent of the android market uses m and hdpi, then we would probably delete all drawables in questions.

So have you guys any idea over how many phones use what kind of dpi?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**EDIT** Updated with recent stats, so you can have some data to compare :)

---

You can check [the official stats](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html):

In March 2019 it looks like this:
[image]

As of May 2017 it was like that:
[image: screen size stats may 2017]

Comment: Thanks. But we are missing xxxhdpi here...?

Comment: yep, not included unfortunately, so I assume it (perhaps) falls into that not shown 0,1% they mention (I updated the image)

Comment: isnt it weired that according to this phones like the samsung s6 make up about 0.1 of the overall phones?

Comment: @user7285912 No, since they are **extremely high priced** devices. Like iPhones.